# Why is the value within my object not changing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code that iterates over two separate objects to drill down, grab the correct value and update it, but the update is not being fulfilled.  When I use debugger, I can see the value get changed, but the main object is not being affected.  I'm sure I'm missing something here, but having another set of eyes would be helpful here.

```
const convert = Object.assign({}, ...this.arr);
goldenListKeys.forEach(key => {
    Object.entries(convert).forEach(item => {
        if (key.name === item[0]) {
            if (key.type === 'Double') {
                item[1] /= 100;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the value of your this.arr?

Comment: Are you expecting the values in `this.arr` to change? `Object.assign` makes a copy, but a shallow copy so your code should work(?) It kinda depends on what `this.arr` is. I'm finding this code hard to read which makes it prone to bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the a value but this value (probably a primitive like `number`) is not a pointer to the actual object.

```
item[1] /= 100;
```

You probably want to do it this way:

```
convert[item[0]] = item[1] / 100
```

This way you are mutating the object

With that said, a slightly more readable syntax could be:

```
goldenListKeys.forEach(key => {
    Object.entries(convert).forEach(([convertKey, convertVal]) => {
        if (key.name === convertKey) {
            if (key.type === 'Double') {
                convert[convertKey] = convertVal / 100;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Very nice, works like a charm.  I like the idea of splitting the key/value pairs like that in the params.  I'll certainly use that approach in the future.  I tried something similar to this in separate iteration, but wrote it wrong.